# Python calculator using tokens

Tags: python, calculator

I'm trying to figure out how to write a calculator program in python.
This is what we got to work with

> Note: The program is only working for a very tiny set of operations.
> You have to add and/or modify code in ALL functions as well as add
> some new functions. Use the syntax charts when you write the
> functions! However, the class SyntaxError is complete as well as
> handling in main of SyntaxError and TokenError.

```
import math
from tokenize import TokenError  
from MA2tokenizer import TokenizeWrapper


class SyntaxError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, arg):
        self.arg = arg
        super().__init__(self.arg)


def statement(wtok, variables):
    """ See syntax chart for statement"""
    result = assignment(wtok, variables)
    return result


def assignment(wtok, variables):
    """ See syntax chart for assignment"""
    result = expression(wtok, variables)
    return result


def expression(wtok, variables):
    """ See syntax chart for expression"""
    result = term(wtok, variables)
    while wtok.get_current() == '+':
        wtok.next()
        result = result + term(wtok, variables)
    return result



def term(wtok, variables):
    """ See syntax chart for term"""
    result = factor(wtok, variables)
    while wtok.get_current() == '*': 
        wtok.next()
        result = result * factor(wtok, variables)
    return result

def factor(wtok, variables):
    """ See syntax chart for factor"""
    if wtok.get_current() == '(':
        wtok.next()
        result = assignment(wtok, variables)
        if wtok.get_current() != ')':
            raise SyntaxError("Expected ')'")
        else:
            wtok.next()
            
    elif wtok.is_number():
        result = float(wtok.get_current())
        wtok.next()

    else:
        raise SyntaxError(
            "Expected number or '('")  
    return result


         
def main():
    """
    Handles:
       the iteration over input lines,
       commands like 'quit' and 'vars' and
       raised exceptions.
    Starts with reading the init file
    """
    
    print("Numerical calculator")
    variables = {"ans": 0.0, "E": math.e, "PI": math.pi}
    # Note: The unit test file initiate variables in this way. If your implementation 
    # requires another initiation you have to update the test file accordingly.
    init_file = 'MA2init.txt'
    lines_from_file = ''
    try:
        with open(init_file, 'r') as file:
            lines_from_file = file.readlines()
    except FileNotFoundError:
        pass

    while True:
        if lines_from_file:
            line = lines_from_file.pop(0).strip()
            print('init  :', line)
        else:
            line = input('\nInput : ')
        if line == '' or line[0]=='#':
            continue
        wtok = TokenizeWrapper(line)

        if wtok.get_current() == 'quit':
            print('Bye')
            exit()
        else:
            try:
                result = statement(wtok, variables)
                variables['ans'] = result
                print('Result:', result)

            except SyntaxError as se:
                print("*** Syntax error: ", se)
                print(
                f"Error occurred at '{wtok.get_current()}' just after '{wtok.get_previous()}'")

            except TokenError as te:
                print('*** Syntax error: Unbalanced parentheses')
 


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I want to start with extending the program to work for - and /, and I tried to change expression to this:

```
def expression(wtok, variables):
    """ See syntax chart for expression"""
    result = term(wtok, variables)
    while wtok.get_current() == '+' or wtok.get_current() == '-':
        if wtok.get_current() == '+'
        wtok.next()
        result = result + term(wtok, variables)
        else
        wtok.next()
        result = result - term(wtok,variables)
    return result

def term(wtok, variables):
    """ See syntax chart for term"""
    result = factor(wtok, variables)
    while wtok.get_current() == '*' or wtok.get_current() == '/': 
        if wtok.get_current() == '*'
        wtok.next()
        result = result * factor(wtok, variables)
        if wtok.get_current() == '/'
        wtok.next()
        result = result / factor(wtok, variables)        
    return result
```

just to see what happens, but it I write 4-3 I get 4.0. And if I write 6-4 I get 6.0. Why? And how do I do to make the calculator acctually calculate with the - ?

Comment: given code seems alright. i am doubting `.get_current()` function

Comment: What are you doubting? .get_current() is used all way during the given code, am  I using it wrong?